# How are bots created to play a game?

Tags: bots, game-engine

Before you actually shout at me for cheating etc. please worry not, I also despise taking advantage of the game by automating it with an application, however with my growing experience (sadly in unrelated web development) I tried to come up with an idea on how to actually simulate player's control and play a game completely from the outside?

Take any possible game, lets start with Mario.

You can move left and right as well as jump or get into the wells. What library would help us achieve it from the program-side? How will it know when to go right, when to jump, how to avoid the bullets or time out the plants? I am not even getting into trying AI to solve it, I am just concerned with the actual control and analysis of the screen (game output and state).

Long story short:
how to control and analyze what happens on the screen, possibly along with some conditional statements?

Thank y'all!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I trust you, hope everyone same too.

When I asked your answer, I just ask about game development aspect, I don't ask about security aspect (because I was game developer, not security engineer)

With automation control for testing: You can try with open source [Airtest Project](https://github.com/AirtestProject/Airtest) from NetEase, or [GAutomation](https://github.com/Tencent/GAutomator) from Tencent. Or you can try implement code yourself by unit test hook click, press or touch event.

Or you can use [selenium tool](https://www.selenium.dev) for game on web browser.

There are more tools but most of them are cheat tools so I not mention here.